# easier way to plot correlation matrix in R without transform data frame

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, correlation, r-corrplot

I have a data frame look like:

```
> head(mydata)
  V1 V2    V3
1  2 14 0.299
2  2 41 0.284
3  2 71 0.307
4  3 43 0.316
5  3 44 0.366
6  3 84 0.405
```

my goal is to plot like: [image]

It seems that many ways need to transform the data frame to used `corrplot` or `ggcorrplot`. Is there any way more easier to plot the data frame to correlation matrix without transforming the data frame?

Comment: Base plotting is quick: `image(cor(df))`. ggplot will require reshaping first, as you don't have the aesthetics you want to plot yet. One option is `GGally::ggcorr(df)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem like a lot of transformation is required for the sample data that you have given.

```
library(corrplot)
corrplot(cor(mydata), method="color", outline="White")
```

[image: Corrplot]